# Contentsize for UIScrollView in App store style card?

Tags: swift

What is the correct calculation for the `contentSize.width` for the `scrollView` that stores the rectangular pics at the top?

I've created the cards, but can't get them to paginate properly. I've tried the following code with 10px spacing between each card and a 20px

```
cell.pictureScrollView.contentSize.width = (cell.pictureScrollViewContainer.frame.width-30) * CGFloat(product.pictures.count)
```

[image: app store grid pic]

Comment: Use UICollection View for displaying a banner type of image. in that, you can give cell minimum spacing.